# Extra column for a table object

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
 moni EmployeeTable%rowtype;
```

I have a Table object moni with row type as of Employee table. 
But instead I also want to add few more columns to moni in addition to Employee table columns.

What is the cleanest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define a cursor and then use its `%rowtype`:

```
declare 
    cursor c_demo is
        select s.*,
               cast (null as varchar2(30)) as extra_column
        from   EmployeeTable s;

    moni c_demo%rowtype;
begin
    moni.extra_column := 'Demo';
end;
```